# Configure SharePoint 2013 in Windows Azure Farm with Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, azure, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2014

I have a SharePoint `Farm` in `Windows Azure` with 3 servers, one for SP2013, one for AD and the 3rd one for SQL. The OS for all the servers is Windows Server 2012. The SQL Server version is 2014. This farm comes with SharePoint pre-installed, but without running the Farm Configuration wizard. In our case, we cannot run this wizard, since we are setting up the environment for Multi tenancy and hence we are configuring the entire farm through PowerShell scripts only.

After configuring our environment using the PowerShell, we observed that `User Profile Synchronization` service is not starting. We tried deleting and recreating this service, but no luck. Some blogs are asking us to install some CUs. But I am not very confident of doing it, since it is Windows Azure and SP was pre-installed. Also, the recommendation is to run the Farm Config Wizard after installing the CU, but we cannot do that, since we configure our farm using PowerShell scripts only. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: I ended up installing the whole farm from scratch but modified  AutoSPInstaller in order to create partitioned service applications.

Comment: Can you check the FIM Synchronization Manager for a possible error or explanation? Located at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell". Are there any relevant Events in Event Viewer or in the ULS logs?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the account that you are using for the "UPS" has the correct level of access try putting it in an admin group first to see if it is that.

Comment: It is running with the farm account and it has been given Local Admin rights also, in addition to other rights.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this finally. We installed the SharePoint Foundation Cumulative Updates for June 2015. After this, we restarted the machine and tried starting the User Profile Sync Service and it started.